# Можно ли передать перменные между stage в gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Можно ли как-то передать переменные между stages? Т.е. на stage-1 я устанавливаю переменную, а на stage-2 её использую.

Answer (score 1):

Можно через файл

```
job1:
  script:
    - echo "A=a" >> job1_vars 
    - ...
    - echo "B=b" >> job1_vars 
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - job1_vars

job2:
  script:
    - source job1_vars
    - echo $A
    - echo $B
```

Comment: Да. Только так у Вас возникнут проблемы, если выполнение будет на разных раннерах или не в шелл-раннере. Тут нужны артефакты.

Comment: да, про артифакты я забыл указать :) Без них файл не передастся даже в пределах одного ранера, если он в докере.

Comment: Поправьте ответ и я его приму