# Использование предопределенных переменных окружения MR GITLAB CI в джобах, которые запускаются после принятия MR

Tags: gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Есть простой конфиг .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build

.docker_image: &docker_image
  image:
    name: foo
    entrypoint: [""]
  tags:
    - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  <<: *docker_image
  script:
    - 'echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID'
    - 'echo $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME'
  only:
    - merge_requests

build:
  stage: build
  <<: *docker_image
  script:
    - export
  only:
    - stage
```

Как мне передать переменные CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID и CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME, которые доступны только при открытом мердж реквесте, в джобу build, которая запустится только после мерджа? Через artifacts не получилось.

Comment: "Через artifacts не получилось." Значит плохо старался https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1242981/340609

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov это не решает мою проблему. Вы воспроизвели кейс?